# Remove item in list of dictionaries if value is empty, "null" or None in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a `JSON` object which contains all sorts of unnecessary values like `"null"`, `""`, `None`. I'd like to remove the whole object if it contains such a value.

```
>>> json.dumps(event, indent=4)
"event" = {
    "status": "COMPLETED",  
    "dataValues": [
    {
        "key": "wiiDcsQ5pdQ",
        "value": "25"
    },
    {
        "key": "RsZ4gQzWPWU",
        "value": "null"
    },
    {
        "key": "L7aO70bcrbP",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "gY6pXRwdThm",
        "value": "null"
    },
    {
        "key": "x1708y0C4C7",
        "value": False
    }
    ]
}
```

My failed attempts:

```
no_values = ["null", "", None]

# no changes/deletions:
[elem for elem in event['dataValues'] if elem['value'] not in no_values]

# TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
[elem for elem in event['dataValues'] if any(s in elem['value'] for s in no_values]
```

How can I do so?

Comment: Did you try to store your first atempt into an variable? Because it does not modify the original

Comment: Yes.. dumb printing/reassignment error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, where I store the data in a variable and evaluate it using your first list comprehension. Note that I'm using a set of ignored_values, which is slightly faster:

```
In [12]: import json

In [13]: json_text = """{
    "status": "COMPLETED",  
    "dataValues": [
    {
        "key": "wiiDcsQ5pdQ",
        "value": "25"
    },
    {
        "key": "RsZ4gQzWPWU",
        "value": "null"
    },
    {
        "key": "L7aO70bcrbP",
        "value": ""
    },
    {
        "key": "gY6pXRwdThm",
        "value": null
    },
    {
        "key": "x1708y0C4C7",
        "value": false
    }
    ]
}"""

In [14]: data = json.loads(json_text)

In [15]: ignored_values = set(["null", "", None])

In [16]: [elem for elem in data['dataValues'] if elem['value'] not in ignored_values]
Out[16]: 
[{u'key': u'wiiDcsQ5pdQ', u'value': u'25'},
 {u'key': u'x1708y0C4C7', u'value': False}]
```

Comment: Minor note: If this is modern Python (Py3.2 or higher), you can get a minor speed up by avoiding the creating of a named `ignored_vals` `set` on each use of such a function, instead having Python load a constant `frozenset`, by doing: `[elem for elem in data['dataValues'] if elem['value'] not in {"null", "", None}]` [The peephole optimizer was upgraded to recognize membership tests in a `set` literal of Python literals, and converts it to a constant `frozenset` once at byte code compile time, then reuses it for free thereafter.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations)

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's an interesting tidbit, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want;

```
ignored_values = ['null', '', None]
data_values = event['dataValues']

In [36]: event['dataValues'] = filter(lambda x: x['value'] not in  ignored_values, data_values) 
In [37]: event
Out[37]:
{'dataValues': [{'key': 'wiiDcsQ5pdQ', 'value': '25'},
  {'key': 'x1708y0C4C7', 'value': False}],
 'status': 'COMPLETED'}
```